# dispatching two actions one after the other in react asyncronously

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, dispatch

Im dispatching two actions one after the other, where the second dispatch makes use of the reducer of first dispatch, but im getting undefined as the second action gets dispatched before the first action is dispatched.

Here is my code:

```
const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
const student = useSelector((state) => state.student);

useEffect(() => {
    const id = auth.user.user;
    dispatch(getStudent(id));
  }, [auth.authenticate]);

if (auth.authenticate) {
    if (auth.user.user_type.is_student == true) {
      if (student.detail && student.detail.length > 0) {
        return <Redirect to={"/student/classes"}></Redirect>;
      } else {
        return <Redirect to={"/student/profile"}></Redirect>;
      }
    } else {
      return <Redirect to={"/faculty/classes"}></Redirect>;
    }
  }
const userLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {
      username,
      password,
    };
    dispatch(login(user));
    
    
  };
```

im trying to redirect it to the pages depending on whether student.detail is populated or not, but it redirects first and executed useEffect function later.

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
if(auth && auth.user && student.detail.length == 0) {
  const id= auth.user.user
  console.log(id)
  dispatch(getStudent(id));
}, [auth]);
```

Dispatch the second action once the auth state in store is updated so that you will git the desired user id.

Or

Use async/await.

Comment: hey thank you for the reply but im also trying to redirect it to different pages based on whether student detail is populated or not. I have edited my question, to include the code for it. can you please have a look.